# MVC Razor- onClick is not firing at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `@Html.RadioButtonFor` which calls a javascript function on `@onCLick`. But it is not fired when page loads.
Here is my code -

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ID, 1, new { Checked = "checked", @onclick = "Check('VAL');" })
```

and javascript function is -

```
function Check(item) {
if (item.toUpperCase() == 'VAL'.toUpperCase()) {
    ......
}}
```

I am not supposed to call the function in `$(document).ready(function () { });`

What I exactly want is the `@onclick` should fire on page load.

Answer (score 4):

you need to trigger the function manually to fire.

Try like this within the javascript tags,

`Sys.Application.add_load(Check);`

Comment: I tried writing `Sys.Application.add_load(Check);` just after the function.

Comment: Can you try like this, `window.onload = function()
                {
                   Check(); //your function to call while load the page.
                };`

Comment: It didnt work for me again. What I exactly want is the `@onclick` should fire on page load.